# how to execute image from public storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I m getting image from form and those save in public , my current code working on local host, but when I push it to server it not execute images.

images saving procedure

```
$image1 = $postData['img']['0']->store('public');
$Add= new Vehicle();
$Add->Img1 = str_replace('public/', '', $image1 );
$Add->save();
```

images execute procedure

```
 <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$add->Img1)}}" alt="">
```

**according to local host images are saving in side ( public/storage )**
*if you have any idea to solve this, please help me*

Comment: Can you check file permissions?

Comment: how?, im new to laravel

Comment: have you on live server linked the storage directory for public use:
in console on live site run: **php artisan storage:link**  details: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try below code?

```
$image1 = $postData['img']['0']->store('public');
$add = new Vehicle(); // Please check variable name camelCase
$add->Img1 = $image1; //Save only the image name in database
$add->save();
```

images execute procedure

```
 <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$add->Img1)}
```

// add / in front of storage folder name

Cheers!